# How to perform non-transactional commit using orient jdbc driver

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1, orientdb2.2

I am connecting to remote database as following using **JDBC driver v2.2.13**

```
Connection conn = (OrientJdbcConnection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:orient:remote:"  + ip + ":" + port + ";" + ip + ":" + port2 + "/"
                    + appName, info);
```

I am getting the following below **warning** as **server logs** when creating edge

```
WARNI {db=Sun} Requested command 'create edge type '_F_ as subclass of 'E'' must be executed outside active transaction: the transactional will be committed and reopen right after it. To avoid this behavior execute it outside a transaction [OrientGraph]
```

From warning it looks like instance (Connection conn) of database is transactional.

One way to solve this is using **OrientgraphNoTx** database instance using Java API.

How can I do "non-transactional" commit or **equivalent** of **OrientgraphNoTx**  for **Orient JDBC driver**

Comment: the command `create edge type '_F_ as subclass of 'E'` isn't a valid OrientDb sql command. To create an edge: `CREATE CLASS _F_ EXTENDS E`
http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Create-Edge.html

Comment: That is not a command but a server log.

Comment: can you show me the code of the jdbc command? I wrote this: `        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    stmt.execute("create class _F_ extends E");
    stmt.close();
`
and it works

Comment: I am successfully able to create Edges, Vertexes. If you could please read question again.

Comment: My problem is,  In server log (linux terminal in which server.sh is running)

I am getting warnning : `Requested command 'create edge type '_F_ as subclass of 'E'' must be executed outside active transaction: the transactional will be committed and reopen right after it. To avoid this behavior execute it outside a transaction [OrientGraph]`

Possible way of solving this wraning is using non-transational instance of orientdb (OrientdbNoTx using java API).

My question is how to do this using JDBC driver?

Thanks?